# No internet connection after the upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 14.04

Upgraded Ubuntu Desktop Server from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS and it can't connect to the internet after. I've also tried issuing `apt-get update` command but I'm get an error as below:

```
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease
```

I didn't change anything in my network configuration (see below)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:24:6c:7c
          inet addr:192.168.23.133  Bcast:192.168.23.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baac:6fff:fe24:6c7c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:44316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4004261 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:176751 (176.7 KB)
          Interrupt:21 Memory:fe6e0000-fe700000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:40241 (40.2 KB)  TX bytes:40241 (40.2 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:6e:1d:9b:48:fb
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.23.133
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.23.255
gateway 192.168.23.17
```

Any advise on this?

## Update

```
~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com


~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.23.17   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.23.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Comment: Hi!! Did you add IP address manually & is your gateway address correct??? what happens when you `ping google.com`?? Also, add the output of `route -n` by [**editing**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/469976/edit) your question.

Comment: hi azker, please see update

Comment: You did not answer my other questions though... BTW, what's **virbr0** doing exactly?? Its a virtual bridge interface used for NAT'ing. May be this is what causing the internet issue. Do you require that interface of what exactly you're doing with the server. Please update accordingly. :)

Comment: virbr0 is there when I created my VMs using virt-manager. Before upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 virbr0 is already there and internet is working fine.

Comment: So how does this Ubuntu server operates as.. is it a VM too or is it a physical machine.. etc?? Also, are you making a use of the `virbr0` device... At last please post the output ot `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.. will see whether changing/updating DNS makes any sense.

Comment: Its just a physical machine with one VM. For now am not using virbr0 because i removed the VM. Please see update

Comment: Perfecto!! I see there is no DNS to resolve. Assuming you know about **vi** editor... Can you edit the file with `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` & add `nameserver 127.0.0.1` on a new line at the end of the file then save it. once done type `sudo service network-manager restart` to restart the network & try to ping a site again. Let me know whether if it works! :)

Comment: Hi azker, is there any other way to restart network configurations? because i don't think i have network-manager package. Issued the command network-manager restart it says network-manager: command not found. If I do this sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart will that also work?

Comment: Yes it will. :)

Comment: hi azkerM, it still doesn't work. ping google.com ping: unknown host google.com :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14644/discussion-between-azkerm-and-dimas).

Comment: Hi! Any luck on this??? Did you manage to get through?