# No internet after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1

Tags: networking

I have a Dell Latitude with Ethernet and Wireless (broadcomm) adapters.  They were both working fine on 12.04.
I upgraded to 14.04.1 via the Software Manager.  Since then I am unable to connect to the internet.  Some info:

- I *can* connect to my wireless router
- I *do* get DHCP info from my router for both wireless and Ethernet
- When I boot to a sysrescuecd (the current version), I get internet access on both Ethernet and wireless.
- nm-tool shows me the same IP, prefix, gateway, and DNS in sysrescuecd as I get in Ubuntu.

Things I've tried:
- I've tried setting the managed=true in the NetworkManager.conf file
- tried setting the IPv6 to ignored (could not figure out how to disable it).
- ping www.google.com fails (I think the error is 'unknown host' but I forgot to write it down)

Any help or would be *GREATLY* appreciated; my searching thus far has not seemed to find a universal cure (the last 'cure' I saw was a clean install of 14.04.1)

Thanks in advance.

** UPDATE **
AzkerM and Wild Man,

First off, thanks so much for your quick response - each time I use this forum, I am  impressed by folks like you who are so willing.

I was able to resolve the issue - see below - but if someone could please tell me *why* it resolved the issue, I think I'll gain a better understanding.

I was able to solve my issue by running

```
sudo dhclient
```

I found that in the following question [at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469976/no-internet-connection-after-the-upgrade-from-12-04-to-14-04-lts)

Can someone please let me know *why* this would solve the issue?

Comment: Hi & welcome to **AU**. Could you please post the output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & `ifconfig` by editing your question.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Glad you found the answer for yourself. You may post it as an answer since you found the solution. Well, I'm guessing that may be  something had gone wrong with either the network config or the dhcp . Because when you run `sudo dhclient` will give you a notification  as; `XXXXXXX answers: File exists`. May be your file got corrupted or didn't exist for some reason, or may be I'm wrong. :)

Comment: AskerM - how do I post as an answer - I see Up/Down tags, favorite tag, and this add comment - not sure how to post as an answer.  Thanks again for all your help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by running

```
sudo dhclient
```