# No internet via wifi/ethernet after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, ethernet

I have just updated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop, and I seem to be having some internet problems. I have no internet connection through wifi or Ethernet, after both working in the previous version.

I am not at all knowledgeable of Ubuntu and its workings, so if you could just tell me what to do, what to show you by just telling me commands etc. I think would be the only way I will understand sorry!

I am asking this after many searches, all being in vein after needing a step involving some sort of internet access, which I can't get! So sorry if it has been answered somewhere, if so, please send me there!

Cheers

This is what I get when using sudo lspci -v:

[lspci -v](http://www.pastebucket.com/52799)

Comment: Please run this in terminal sudo lspci -v and add all the results to your answer

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you upgrade from? It looks like the kernel network drivers do not start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or a similar) issue with my laptop after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. After some searching I found a fix at askubuntu:

[No internet after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512353/no-internet-after-upgrading-from-12-04-to-14-04-1)

i.e.

```
sudo dhclient
```

solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. Start simple with:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

if that does not help:

```
sudo service networking force-reload
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked restart gets; stop: Job failed while stopping; start: Job is already running: networking. reload gets; reload: Job is not running: networking. Thanks though, feel free to keep the ideas coming!