# After routine update on 14.04, cannot even SEE internet (no ethernet, no wifi)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, ethernet

I am posting this question from my Windows desktop, because as of this morning my laptop is no longer even an internet accessible device, and doesn't even seem to think it's *supposed* to be an internet accessible device.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit. The laptop is an Asus X551CA, and I got it in 2013 April.

Last night, I installed a routine Ubuntu update. I then restarted my computer. This morning, I have no internet. Like, at all. When I open up Firefox, every single tab says it failed to load the requested page. At the top right corner of the screen, *there isn't even an internet icon*. I tried connecting my ethernet cable, but it didn't even react at all.

I tried restarting like three or four times. It doesn't help. The internet is still missing.

I tried the following terminal commands, as suggested by responders to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515819/no-internet-via-wifi-ethernet-after-14-04-upgrade).

```
sudo service networking restart

sudo service networking force-reload

sudo dhclient

sudo apt-get update
```

Each one returned errors.

The first one returned­ this.

```
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

The second one returned this.

```
reload: Job is not running: networking
```

The third one returned this.

```
avahi-daemon stop/waiting
```

And the fourth one, after spitting out a large wall of text, then returned this.

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45
```

I have no idea what to do. It's the very end of the semester, and I have a research project that I need to complete by the end of monday. So it is, to say the least, absolutely *imperative* that my internet be working soon. Please, please help.

Comment: I've got the same problem... no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you add the output of `rfkill list` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arose due to a regression introduced with a fix for `libnl3` [bug #1511735](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735).

I resolved this issue by **downloading a newer version of** `network-manager` from another computer with a functional network connection.

Here are the respective download links for the [amd64](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb) and [i386](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_i386.deb) architectures.

Copy the `.deb` file to a USB stick and install it on the affected computer with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb
```

For more information, please, refer to:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/771692/164341
- https://askubuntu.com/a/727462/164341

Comment: I followed the steps in your second link at the end, and everything is working fine now! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

My network was down after my last update as well.   I ran update/upgrade from recovery mode and that solved it.

I had to use the root terminal in recovery mode because my recovery mode is buggy.  So I had to mount the drive RW manually and bring the network up, ifonfig eth1 up , which I don't think you have to do otherwise.

Be real, be sober.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)